# Bounded Point in Uniform Spaces

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

I'm currently studying uniform spaces and have come across a problem I don't know how to solve. Given any vicinity $U$ of a non-discrete uniform space, I want to prove that for every pair of points $a, b$ there is a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(a, b) \in \underbrace{U \circ U \circ U ... \circ U}_\textrm{n compositions}$. I've spent a few days thinking about the problem and haven't gotten anywhere.  I fear this should be really obvious, and the fact that I'm not able to prove it means there is something wrong with my way of reasoning with uniformities.  Could anyone point me in the direction of a proof?

Comment: Do you mean an *entourage* by a *vicinity*? If so I think this proposition cannot be proved because there are counterexamples.

Comment: @user138171 Yes, I mean entourage.  Could you provide a counterexample?  I've not been able to think of any.

Comment: Let $U$ be an equivalence relation on a set $X$. the set $[\![U,X^2]\!]=\{S\subseteq X^2\mid U\subseteq S\}$ is a uniformity on $X$. take $U$.

Comment: It isn’t even true if you require the space to be Hausdorff (and hence Tikhonov). Let $X=\{0,1\}^\Bbb N$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology; points of $X$ are infinite sequences of 0s and 1s. For $n\in\omega$ and $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle,y=\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in X$ let $x\sim_n y$ iff $x_k=y_k$ for all $k<n$, and let $U_n=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times X:x\sim_n y\}$. Then $\{U\subseteq X\times X:\exists n\in\Bbb N(U\supseteq U_n)\}$ is a uniformity on $X$, and the associated topology is compact Hausdorff. However, each $U_n$ is an equivalence relation, so for ...

Comment: ... each $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $U_n\circ U_n=U_n$.